# Перебор объектов (each) по событию boundschange Яндекс Карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Здравствуйте!
Насколько допустима такая конструкция:

```
myMap.events.add('boundschange', function (event) { 
    myMap.geoObjects.each(function(geoObject) {  
    console.log(geoObject.properties.get('idobj'));  //выводит идентификаторы объектов
    });
});
```

Эту конструкцию я хочу использовать для поиска объектов в активной области (код упрощен для наглядности). свойство idobj присутствует.

```
Сейчас после ее срабатывания карта выводится криво, с ошибками, хотя идентификаторы я получаю.
```

Полностью упрощенный код здесь:
https://travelandia.ru/maptest.php

Answer (score 0):

Такая конструкция допустима, но не в вашем случае. myMap.geoObjects.each пробежиться по всем непосредственным детям коллекции геообъектов myMap.geoObjects. В вашем случае это только лишь один Clusterer, который добавляется на строчке

```
myMap.geoObjects.add(result.search('geometry.type == "Point"').clusterize({gridSize: 80, clusterDisableClickZoom: true}));
```

Вам нужно сохранять ссылку на этот кластер. Вызывать метод geoObject, а дальше работать со списком как с обычным массивом.
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Clusterer-docpage/#getGeoObjects